# Advanced Custom Fields plugin - get text from editor field and save it in a variable

Tags: plugins, advanced-custom-fields, editor

In ACF I added a custom editor field but when I try to save it's text into a variable and output the value with js to the console it gives me an empty string.

Here's my code:

```
<?php $test = the_field('text'); ?>
```

And the javascript:

```
<script>
     var v = '<?php echo $test; ?>';
     console.log(v);
</script>
```

I need to get the text value because I need to check if there are list items in it. What am I doing wrong? Or is there a special method for that? If i try to output it directly to the front end...

```
<?php the_field('text'); ?>
```

...it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`the_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/) is a echo statement use [`get_field()`](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/) instead.

You can't save echoed value into a variable, for that you may need to use output buffer `ob_start`.In your case `get_field` function should work.